403 при попытке установить плагин wordpress через запросы
появилась нужда устанавливать плагин для сайта wordpress через запросы python:
with requests.Session() as session:
    session.headers.update(headers)
    try:
        response_post = session.post(
            'https://site.com/wp-login.php', # логин
            data=payload,
            headers=headers,
            timeout=30
        )
        response_post = response_post.text
        r3 = session.get('https://site.com/wp-admin/plugin-install.php?tab=upload', headers=headers) # получить CSRF
        print(r3.text)
        look_for = 'name="_wpnonce" value="'
        nonceText = r3.text.split(look_for, 1)[1]
        nonce = nonceText[0:10]
        print(nonce)

        try:
            files = {
                'pluginzip': ('laravel.zip', open('laravel.zip', 'rb')),
                '_wpnonce': nonce,
                '_wp_http_referer': (None, 'https://site.com/wp-admin/plugin-install.php?tab=upload'),
                'install-plugin-submit': (None, 'Install Now')
            }
            r4 = session.post("https://site.com/wp-admin/update.php?action=upload-plugin", headers=headers,
                              files=files)
            print(r4.status_code) # 200-хорошо, 403-плохо :(

сообщение со страницы при ошибке 403 будет вот таким:
<body id="error-page">
    <div class="wp-die-message">The link you followed has expired.</p><p><a href="https://vanceslane.com/wp-login.php">Please try again.</a></div></body>
</html>

помогите пожалуйста исправить эту ошибку с запросом на установку плагина
P.S SCRF токен вроде находит правильно, но их там несколько

Не понимаю такой нужды, но для работы внешних приложений с ВП у него есть АПИ

да, но мне нужно ставить кастом плагин (.zip) который находится локально у меня, а насколько я понял через апи так не сделать( (либо я долблюсь в глаза, и соотвественно попрошу тыкнуть меня носом)

Локально:! Смысла в телодвижениях ещё меньше. Но вообще пофик где лежит плагин. Лишь бы был доступ. Но если локально, то может лучше заюзать wp-cli См описание на русском

я имел ввиду что именно ПЛАГИН находится локально, а не вордпресс. доступ к вп админке, как обычно.

Я всё так и понял. (не понимаю только "нужды" (ака смысла) этой затеи. Вплоть до того - какие проблемы питоновским скриптом (или чем-то ещё) загрузить файлы на сервер.)

если вкратце, заказчик попросил массовый чекер на валидность + установка плагина на валидные админ-панели, я добился того что плагин успешно устанавливается, но с активацией трудности( проблемы с wpnonce, где-то его принимает, а где-то нет(в запросе на активацию), пишет your link has expired

Какие ещё "валидные админ-панели"?!!! Какая "массовая валидность"? Чего:? Причём это всё к  установке плагинов без доступа в админку вообще? И вообще может стоит отдать заказ специалисту? Он хотя бы выяснит что реально и зачем нужно и объяснит заказчику если он хочет неестесвеного.

Я кажется понял про массовость - хакинг. Нет, тут без меня.
